# Tkinter - Iterating default text entry

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI which will enable me to create folders with iterating names each time I click a button, i.e. 'folder_1', 'folder_2, 'folder_3',... which is isn't too difficult.

But, I also want the ability to manually change the number at which the iteration starts: I can enter '10' in an entry box and click the button, which would create 'folder_10' and each time I click the button after that it would continue to iterate, i.e folder_11, folder_12, folder_13,...

It would also be very helpful if the entry box contained the number of the next folder, as a default (that I can change manually), to be created when I click the button.

I've been trying to get something like this to work but no luck:

```
from tkinter import *


master = Tk()
master.counter = 0

def create_folder():
    newfoldername = 'Folder_'+e1.get()+'/'
    master.counter += 1
    print(newfoldername)
    #...folder creation here (I know how to do this...)


e1 = Entry(master)
e1.insert(0, master.counter)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

Button(master, text='Create folder', command=create_folder).grid(row=1,
column=1)

mainloop()
```

I am newbie to python so this might be really simple...

Thanks.

Comment: You only used `master.counter` once, during the original creation of the Entry.  You'd have to `.set()` the Entry to the new value of the counter inside `create_folder()`.

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? What is the program doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use `IntVar()`(If you type string in the `Entry` and use `.get()`,you will get error.) or `StringVar()`.

```
from tkinter import *


master = Tk()
master.counter = IntVar()
master.counter.set(0)

def create_folder():
    newfoldername = 'Folder_'+str(master.counter.get())+'/'
    master.counter.set(master.counter.get()+1)
    print(newfoldername)
    #...folder creation here (I know how to do this...)


e1 = Entry(master, textvariable=master.counter)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

Button(master, text='Create folder', command=create_folder).grid(row=1,
column=1)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Shows the next value in the Entry box and creates directory with that number. If you change the value in the Entry box, it continues from there.

```
from tkinter import *


master = Tk()
master.counter = 0

def create_folder():
    newfoldername = 'Folder_'+e1.get()+'/'
    master.counter = int(e1.get())
    master.counter += 1
    e1.delete(0, END)
    e1.insert(0, str(master.counter))
    print(newfoldername)
    #...folder creation here (I know how to do this...)


e1 = Entry(master)
e1.insert(0, master.counter)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

Button(master, text='Create folder', command=create_folder).grid(row=1,
column=1)

mainloop()
```